# output of ext gwt label rootpanel,get.add?

Tags: gwt, extjs

i have `<div id="abc"></div>`
I executed `RootPanel.get("abc").add(new Label("aaaaaaaaaaaaa"));` from GWT.

then acutually GWT generates what kind of html tag??
is it like `<font>aaaaaaaaaaaa</font>`????

which i mean the output will be
`<div id="abc"><font aaaaaaaaaaaa></font></div>` ??

Comment: It seems like you keep creating an account to ask questions. Either that or there are a lot of users named "msaif" that ask questions about GWT + ExtJS

Answer (score 0):

GWT doesn't generate any <font> tags as far as I know; the tag is deprecated in the HTML spec. Labels are based on a div element, so the output from your example code will be `<div id='abc'><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></div>`

The standard replacement these days for the <font> tag is the <span> tag, which works the same way and does everything the font tag can do via css. To get one of these instead, try `RootPanel.get("abc").add(new InlineLabel("aaaaaaaaaaa"));`